# Displaying 2D array results excluding nulls in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm creating an array that will sort arrayString[10][2] and then display the results to the user using JOptionPane.  The length of the 2D array is irrelevant, just note that it will not be completely populated resulting in nulls.  When I display the information to the user  I want to exclude the nulls.  Currently I have used a variable "isNull" to make this work but I know it is inefficient and am looking for the proper way to accomplish this.

**The Array with two rows of data**

```
String arrayString[][] = new String[10][2];
arrayString[0][0] = "Doe";
arrayString[0][1] = "John";

arrayString[1][0] = "Doe";
arrayString[1][1] = "Jane";
```

**The actual program logic**

```
String output = "";
int isNull = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayString.length; i++)
{ 
  for (int j = 0; j < arrayString[i].length; j++)
  { 
    if ( arrayString[i][j] == null )
    {
      isNull = 1;
      break;
    }
    else
    output += arrayString[i][j] + "  ";
    isNull = 0;
  }
  if(isNull == 1)
    break;
  else
    output += " \n";
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,output,"Results",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Thanks for all the help guys, I wen't back through my code and reevaluated it and got an answered I'm satisfied with on my own.  Thanks for the responses though.

**Solved**

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayString.length; i++)
{ 
  for (int j = 0; j < arrayString[i].length; j++)
  { 
    if ( arrayString[i][0] == null)
      break;
    else
    output += arrayString[i][j] + "  ";
  }
  if ( arrayString[i][0] == null)
    break;
  else
  output += " \n";
}
```

Comment: I think you rather need a `List<List<String>>`. Or if you have any relation between `"A"` and `"one"`, then you can use a different data structure, but you need to tell the relationship for that.

Comment: I updated the data in the array to better reflect the list. I am unfamiliar with List<List<String>> but am looking into it.  Thank you for your help @RohitJain.

Comment: @Matt not bad, buddy, keep up doing good work

Comment: @Flextra Thanks for the positive feedback and your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Make a List of all anagram groups above size threshold.
List<List<String>> winners = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for (List<String> l : m.values())
    if (l.size() >= minGroupSize)
        winners.add(l);

// Sort anagram groups according to size
Collections.sort(winners, new Comparator<List<String>>() {
    public int compare(List<String> o1, List<String> o2) {
        return o2.size() - o1.size();
    }});

// Print anagram groups.
for (List<String> l : winners)
    System.out.println(l.size() + ": " + l);
```

Look at this post more accurate: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/algorithms/index.html#sorting

Comment: @RohitJain no, i'm just copied a sample from java tutorial instead of him. a bit help is not so bad, just no reason to add something more here... sorry... but if you think that i should delete this message, I will agree to do  that

Comment: I appreciate the quick responses from both @Flextra and RohitJain but as I'm sure this answer and it's documentation are the correct way to get my desired results I believe it is out of my depth of understanding.  I will re-read over the documentation again to try and grasp the concepts being taught so I can accept this answer but I will need some time to try and solve this the proper way.